# Access attribute from other model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am a Rails beginner building my first web app.

At the moment I have two models: **Users** and **Patients**. A User has_many patients and a Patient belongs_to a User. In the Patients controller I added the following line to the create action to show only the Patients that belong to the logged in User in patients#index.

```
@patient.user_id = current_user.id
```

In the table on patients#index it shows the user_id

```
<td><%= patient.user_id %></td>
```

The User model has a company_name:string attribute.

How can I show the :company_name from my User model on this page - instead of the user_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of your `user` association:

```
<td><%= patient.user.company_name %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Law Of Dementer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Further to `Marek`'s answer, you may wish to look into the [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method

I don't know for sure whether this will help you directly, as `delegate` only works with `belongs_to` and `has_one` methods (although I've got it working tentatively with `has_many` before)

--

```
#app/models/patient.rb
Class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :company_name, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<%= patient.user_company_name %>
```

More cosmetic than anything - but always handy to have, considering you can have so many associations all over the place

Comment: Thanks Rick! I will read up on this method and the Wikipedia page!